# Sum selected values in html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm writing a simple calculator that adds up a continuous stream of numbers on an HTML page limited to 100 nodes at any time.

I can select the nodes on the current page with:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('span.class');
var len = els.length;
arr = [];
for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
      var no = els[i].innerHTML;
      arr.push(no);
}
console.log(no);
```

Here's what I've been exploring, maybe you can suggest a simpler or improved method?

> ```
>  1. Select values, push into an array.
>  2. Store array in a cookie, or htmllocalstorage
>  3. every 5 seconds, push new values into 2nd array.
>  4. Read 1st array and compare to 2nd array.
>  5. create new array. sum values. store new array.
> ```

I've been having trouble comparing the values with loops. **Is there a splice function for 2 arrays with overlapping values?**

In the example below, the desired array would be: 
[1,2,3,2,1,8,7]

```
var arr1 = ['1','2','3','2','1'];
var arr2 = ['3','2','1','8','7']; // the first two values are now truncated off because current line is 102
var arr3 = [];

for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
{
  for (j=0; j<arr2.length; j++)
  {
    // number exists in both arrays
    // next number is next index
    if (arr1[i] == arr2[j] && arr1[i+1] == arr2[j+1] && arr1[i+2] == arr2[j+2]) 
    {
      arr3.push(arr1[i]);
      //console.log(arr1[i]+ ' '+arr2[j] + 'true ' + arr1[i+1] + ' ' + arr2[j+1]+ arr1[i+2] + ' ' + arr2[j+2]);
    }
    else
    {
      //arr3 = [];
      //console.log(arr1[i]+ ' '+arr2[j] + ' false');
    }
  }
}
var end = arr3[0]-1;
var arr4 = arr1.slice(0,end);
var arr5 = arr4.concat(arr2);
//console.log(arr5);

var total=0;
for (k=0;k<arr5.length; k++)
{
total += parseInt(arr5[k]);
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Is there a way to receive the values one at a time?

Comment: Comeon, being 100+ rep user, how can you ask a question without showing code/efforts?

Comment: We can't understand your question unless you show your some code to us.

Comment: Why are you using two arrays to sum values that could/should be contained in one?

Comment: So, get all the values in one array. If there are more than 100 values in that array, decide if you want the first hundred, the last hundred or the middle hundred; trim the array to that section and *then* get the total..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by comparing values starting from the end of the first array, with the corresponding values in the second array. If the common chunk(`['3','2','1']` in your example) matches exactly, that is to say that the first n(=`chunk.length`) values in the second array and the last n values in the first array are identical, then you can concatenate the two arrays to get the overlapped result.

```
function overlap(a, b) {
    var counter = a.length - 1;
    var startingIndex = b.indexOf(a[counter]);
    while (b[--startingIndex] == a[--counter]) {}
    if (startingIndex == -1) {
        return a.slice(0, counter + 1).concat(b);
    } else {
        return a.concat(b);
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/qwGP6/5/)

Comment: Can you explain this part? while (b[--startingIndex] == a[--counter]) {}

Comment: It's the same as writing `while (b[startingIndex] == a[counter]) {startingIndex = startingIndex-1; counter = counter-1;}`. It keeps on reducing the index and counter as long as the values match.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to remove overlapping elements at the start of the second array.

Maybe you can compare sub-strings instead of array elements.

consider these strings

```
var input1 = "1,2,3,2,1";
var input2 = "3,2,1,8,7";
```

If you can create a loop to generate the substring "3,2,1" , you can just replace the input and get rid of the first 3 numbers to get this string "8,7"

Concatenate the strings and do what you need to get your array.